# Delete rows from a table in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I delete a row from a table if it has a foreign key?
I have this stored procedure but when I execute it it gives me this error :`The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK__Pilot_Fli__pilot__4E88ABD4". The conflict occurred in database "Airline Reservation", table "dbo.Pilot_Flight", column` 'pilot_id'.

```
create procedure DeletePilot
    (@id INTEGER,@result varchar(70) output)
as
    If NOT Exists ( Select * From Pilot
            Where pilot_id=@id) 
    Begin
        Set @result='There is no record with that ID'
        RETURN
    END

    Delete from Pilot
    where pilot_id=@id
    set @result='Record was deleted'
    RETURN
GO
select * from Pilot
Declare @res varchar(70)
EXEC DeletePilot 7,@res OUTPUT
print(@res)
```

Can anyone help me please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to either run a statement like this (if it's `nullable`):

```
UPDATE Pilot_Flight
SET pilot_id = NULL
WHERE pilot_id = @id
```

or do this:

```
DELETE Pilot_Flight WHERE pilot_id = @id
```

Either way you have to do one or the other **before** the `DELETE` from `Pilot`.

Comment: @user3043278, I'm glad I could be of assistance!

Answer (score 1):

There are records in dbo.Pilot_Flight that reference records in dbo.Pilot.

You could delete the records in Pilot_Flight before deleting the records in Pilot, enable ([cascade delete](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620086/CASCADE-in-SQL-Server-with-example) which would delete records in Pilot_Flight when Pilot records are deleted (bad), or disable the foreign key reference... (worse).